How can rotate an object about a specific point that I know the coordinates of
I'm sure my problem is very simple, but I'm a newcomer to Blender.
I have an object, that I want to rotate using ROTATE or TRANSFORM, but I don't want the pivot point to be the Median.  I want the pivot point to be a point that has known coordinates.  How can I specify this pivot point to Blender?
I tried to set the pivot point with no avail.
Thank you very much.

Hit N to show the side panel then select the View tab. you'll see a 3D Cursor section on that tab and you can change its location there. Then set the Transform Pivot Point on the top toolbar to 3D Cursor and you're good to go.

When you're finished you can reset the cursor to the World Origin with Shift-C

And, if you want the object to always rotate about that point, you can use Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor to set that location as its permanent rotation center, relative to the geometry.

There's also a whole range of options available via the Shift-S pie menu.

Thank you very much for your answer.
